# Storing and processing large XML files with Heroku?

Tags: ruby, xml, heroku, xml-parsing, storage

I'm working on an application that needs to store a large 2GB+ XML file for processing, and I'm facing two problems:

1. How do I process the file? Loading the whole file into Nokogiri at once won't work. It quickly eats up memory and, as far as I can tell, the process gets nuked from orbit. Are there Heroku-compatible ways to quickly/easily read a large XML file located on a non-Heroku server in smaller chunks?
2. How do I store the file? The site is set up to use S3, but the data provider needs FTP access to upload the XML file nightly. S3 via FTP is apparently a no-go, and storing the file on Heroku won't work either, as it'll only be seen by the dyno that owns it and is susceptible to being randomly purged. Has anyone encountered this type of constraint before, and if so, how'd you work around it?

Comment: Use extended VTD-XML, you can do xpath (full set) over xml files up to 256GB in size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time we prefer parsing the entire file that has been pulled into memory because it's easier to jump back and forth, extracting this and that as our code needs. Because it's in memory, we can do random access easily, if we want.

For your need, you'll want to start at the top of the file, and read each line, looking for the tags of interest, until you get to the end of the file. For that, you want to use [Nokogiri::XML::SAX](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/SAX.html) and [Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Parser](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/SAX/Parser.html), along with the events in [Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Document](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/SAX/Document.html). Here's a summary of what it does, from Nokogiri's site:

> The basic way a SAX style parser works is by creating a parser, telling the parser about the events we’re interested in, then giving the parser some XML to process. The parser will notify you when it encounters events your said you would like to know about.

SAX is a different beast than dealing with the DOM, but it can be very fast, and is a lot easier on memory.

If you wanted to load the file in smaller chunks, you could process the XML inside an `OpenURI.open` or `Net::HTTP` block, so you'd be getting it in TCP packet-size chunks. The problem then is that your lines could be split, because TCP doesn't guarantee reading by lines, but by blocks, which is what you'll see inside the read loop. Your code would have to peel off partial lines at the end of the buffer, and then prepend them to the read buffer so the next block read finishes the line.

Answer (score 0):

1. You'll need a streaming parser. Have a look at https://github.com/craigambrose/sax_stream
2. You could run your own FTP server on EC2? Or use a hosted provider such as https://hostedftp.com/